# Alternative Way To Write Yield

Tags: c#, yield, yield-return, yield-keyword

Is there a way to get rid of the `.FirstOrDefault()` with the following setup.  I love using the yield statement but I want to condense the IsRequired method to the point where I dont have to use `.FirstOrDefault()`.

PlayerValidator

```
protected override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(PlayerModel entity, IValidationProvider validationProvider)
        {
            yield return ValidationResultHelper.IsRequired(entity.Profile.FirstName, "First Name").FirstOrDefault();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entity.Profile.LastName))
                yield return new Required("Last Name");
        }
```

ValidatorHelper

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IsRequired(string text, string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        yield return new Required(name);
}
```

Comment: Is your code meant to return `null` if the `FirstName` is valid?

Comment: Nope, nothing just like the LastName return.

Comment: Well I'm not a `yield return` virtuoso, but won't the `OrDefault` part of `FirstOrDefault` give you a `null` value back if the `FirstName` is not `null` or whitespace?

Comment: Why does `IsRequired()` return `IEnumerable<>` at all if it will only ever return a single value?

Comment: Your right, just tested returns NULL, not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` would be another option (and it wouldn't return erroneously `null` in the case that there is no validation error as in your example):

```
protected override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(PlayerModel entity, IValidationProvider validationProvider)
{
    foreach (var result in ValidationResultHelper.IsRequired(entity.Profile.FirstName, "First Name"))
        yield return result;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entity.Profile.LastName))
        yield return new Required("Last Name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not as familiar with `yield return` as I could be, but in this case I think the way you've used `yield return` in `IsRequired` is using the wrong tool for the job. I would structure it slightly differently:

## `ValidatorHelper`

```
// Note this function is almost unnecessary and might be better
// implemented in AddIfRequired if validation is this trivial.
public static bool IsRequired(string text)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text);
}
```

## `PlayerValidator`

```
private static void AddIfRequired(string text, string name, List<ValidationResult> validationResults)
{
    if (ValidatorHelper.IsRequired(text))
        requiredList.Add(new Required(name));
}

protected override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(PlayerModel entity, IValidationProvider validationProvider)
{
    List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

    AddIfRequired(entity.Profile.FirstName, "First Name", validationResults);
    AddIfRequired(entity.Profile.LastName, "Last Name", validationResults);
    // ...

    return validationResults;
}
```

If you really want to use `yield return` and save yourself creating a list and validating all fields each time (although I don't think this would be a performance problem), you could make `AddIfRequired` into `ValidationResultIfRequired` and `Validate` into:

```
ValidationResult validationResult;

// ...

validationResult = ValidationResultIfRequired(entity.Profile.FirstName, "First Name");
if (validationResult != null)
    yield return validationResult;

validationResult = ValidationResultIfRequired(entity.Profile.LastName, "Last Name");
// etc
```